# Display Format Bar Below Toolbar in Mac App

Tags: macos, cocoa, toolbar

Some time iOS developer, first time Mac developer. I'm trying to add a Format Bar to a Mac OS X app. Same as Pages. With buttons, below Toolbar, and the ability to show and hide.

[image]

I started down the path of creating a custom view and adding it as a subview of the MainMenu.xib > Window > View, but I am not having luck.

I created an outlet to the view in the AppDelegate, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I can show and hide this view, but what happens with resizing all the views and contents below? In Pages it is quite a dynamic layout.

- Should this view live in the MasterVC, instead of AppDelegate?
- Is a CustomView even the right container for this? It seems quite different than iOS. I can't even seem to set a background color on it.

[image]

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to proceed. I have to assume that this is a pretty common implementation. I'm probably missing something obvious that's making it harder than it needs to be. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "The Outlet I put in AppDelegate is never displayed in IB"? If you've correctly created a property in your app delegate that's an IBOutlet, then it will appear. Post the code in your appDelegate.h where you created this outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is an Apple control called [inspectorBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstextview_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000373-SW105). It can be enabled for an NSTextView in interface builder, or using:

```
setUsesInspectorBar
```

Unfortunately, it does seem to have [quite a few limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785350/positioning-inspector-bar-for-nstextview). As far as I can tell:

- No way to show / hide with public API
- No way to customize the buttons displayed
- Only works with an NSTextView. No to NSTextField

So while inspectorBar directly addressed my original broad question of displaying the formatting tools seen in Pages, I may still go with rdelmar's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an NSBox, rather than as custom view as your starting point -- if you set the box type to custom, then you can set a fill color as well as border type and color. As far as resizing all the views, you should be able to do that with the struts and springs in IB.  And, yes, this view should be in a MasterVC (or some other controller object) rather than in your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It sounds like this can be used with anything. A friend turned me on to inspectorBar that works with NSTextView. It has some limitations, so I may give this a go still.