# Is it possible to modify the font size dropdown of NSTextView's Inspector Bar?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have coded a macOS app using Cocoa and Swift. In my app I use an `NSTextView` which displays the inspector bar, i.e. `.usesInspectorBar` is set to `true`. I would like to modify the default font sizes displayed in the dropdown:

[image: NSTextView Inspector Bar's font size dropdown]

Documentation on this is slim and I have had no success. If it's possible I assume it might be through `NSFontManager`. I looked at the API for `NSFontManager` and tried to modify the font menu but nothing I do actually alters the inspector bar.

Comment: Some older info on inspector bar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785350/positioning-inspector-bar-for-nstextview. I suppose not much will have changed, it's private.

Comment: The inspector bar gets the sizes from the font panel. The list of sizes is editable but this is a bit buggy.

Comment: @Willeke could you elaborate on how to do this and why it is buggy? Looking at the [documentation for NSFontPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfontpanel), I don't see anything regarding the font list.

Comment: Font Panel -> Action button menu -> Edit Sizes…. Restart the app to update the inspector bar.

Comment: @Willeke I was looking to do this programatically. Probably not doable in that case.

Comment: There's no API, but the list of font sizes is stored in user defaults.

Comment: @Willeke Is that globally accessible and if so, what is the key?

Comment: The font sizes are stored in user defaults of the app. You can find the key in the preferences file.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for your help. I was able to do it programatically by manipulating the UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke)'s comments, I figured out this can be done programatically by executing the following line in AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","18","24","36","48"], forKey: "NSFontPanelSizeList")
```